# How to display second Y-axis's values in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I like to display values on second y-axis (right vertical) in matplotlib. 
My code is as follow.

```
def main(files):
    plt.style.use('ggplot')
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax1.set_xlabel('iteration')
    losslabel = ax1.set_ylabel('loss')
    losslabel.set_color("red")
    accuracylabel = ax2.set_ylabel('accuracy %')
    accuracylabel.set_color("green")
    disp_results(fig, ax1, ax2, loss_iterations, losses, accuracy_iterations, accuracies, accuracies_iteration_checkpoints_ind, fileName, color_ind=i)
    plt.show()


def disp_results(fig, ax1, ax2, loss_iterations, losses, accuracy_iterations, accuracies, accuracies_iteration_checkpoints_ind, fileName, color_ind=0):
    colors = dict(mcolors.BASE_COLORS, **mcolors.CSS4_COLORS)
    acrIterations =[]
    top_acrs={}
    if accuracies.size:
        if  accuracies.size>4:
            top_n = 4
        else:
            top_n = accuracies.size -1      
        temp = np.argpartition(-accuracies, top_n)
        result_indexces = temp[:top_n]
        temp = np.partition(-accuracies, top_n)
        result = -temp[:top_n]
        for acr in result_indexces:
            acrIterations.append(accuracy_iterations[acr])
            top_acrs[str(accuracy_iterations[acr])]=str(accuracies[acr])

        sorted_top4 = sorted(top_acrs.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
        maxAcc = np.amax(accuracies, axis=0)
        iterIndx = np.argmax(accuracies)
        maxAccIter = accuracy_iterations[-1]
        maxIter =   accuracy_iterations[-1]
        consoleInfo = format('\n[%s]:Test accuracy Vs Train loss [from 0 to %s ] = [Iteration %s]: %s ' %(fileName,maxIter,maxAccIter ,maxAcc))
        plotTitle = format('Test accuracy Vs Train loss(%s) [Iteration %s]: %s ' % (fileName,maxAccIter, maxAcc))
        print (consoleInfo)

        print ('Top 4 accuracies:'+str(sorted_top4))        
        plt.title(plotTitle)
    ax1.plot(loss_iterations, losses, colors['red'])
    ax2.plot(accuracy_iterations, accuracies, colors['green'], label=str(fileName))
    ax2.plot(accuracy_iterations[accuracies_iteration_checkpoints_ind], accuracies[accuracies_iteration_checkpoints_ind], 'o', colors['red'])
```

The plot is fine, just that right vertical axis values are not displayed.
Plot is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lvc7xdkanogr7k0/Figure_1.png?dl=0).

[image]

Python code and log files are [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uhkhz9qjvfpgu0q/CaffePlot%20-%20Copy.py?dl=0) and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i68mvr0afe1x9cm/NUMBERPLATE_480x480.log?dl=0).

Comment: The right axis only has a single tick, `#FF0000`. Since the code is not runnable (see [mcve]), this is pretty much all one can say for now.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have updated code and log file

Comment: Second line ax2.plot makes not to display the values on right side y-axis. I removed it and it displays